# Replace start and end tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to parse my website and save new version to variable.

For example i have code like this:

```
<body>
  <div data-newname="test"></div>
  <div data-newname="test2"></div>
</body>
```

so the new code should be:

```
<body>
  {{Start:test}}{{End::test}}
  {{Start:test2}}{{End::test2}}
</body>
```

I was want to use replacewiths method but this is not gonna help me :( maybe regular expression?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? It seems like you're trying to turn the HTML into a format which can be used in a templating library - however depending on the library you use JS may be too late in the pipeline to do this.

Comment: exactly - templating library. I need parse my html to this format and send to the backend - then backend will be doing with this whatever he want

Comment: Why wouldn't a replace work?

Comment: I know how to replace the start tag, but how can I detect which one is my close tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to re-wrap the elements.

Because overwriting the HTML of the outer elements will drop the nested elements from the collection, I've wrapped it in a `while` to ensure that the nested ones get updated as well.

```js
while ($("[data-newname]").length) {
  $("[data-newname]").replaceWith(function() {
    let data = $(this).data("newname");
    return `{{Start:${data}}}${$(this).html()}{{End::${data}}}`
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-newname="test">
  <div data-newname="nested">Nested</div>
</div>
<div data-newname="test2">Test2</div>
```

Comment: youre awesome :-)

Comment: hmm, but what about if there will be div in div..? if i have div with data tags and inside next div with data tags - doesnt work :(

Comment: love it. Thank you :)

Comment: If the downvoter wants to explain their issue with the answer I'd be happy to address.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

**UPDATE:** Reverse order replace the innermost first

```js
$($('[data-newname]').get().reverse()).replaceWith(function() {
  let data = $(this).data('newname')
  return `{{Start:${data}}}${$(this).html()}{{End::${data}}}`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-newname="test1">
  Test1
  <div data-newname="test2">Test2</div>
</div>
<div data-newname="test3">Test3</div>
```

Comment: the same thing is like in answer below - this work only without nested elements: 
<div data-newname="test"><div data-newname="test">Test</div></div> - not work